# How to send a GET request in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I see this example here: http://damn.ihateblue.net/2011/09/24/actionscript-3-send-getpost/

Which looks pretty good. But the loader seems overly complicated. What if I don't need to listen for a response? Can this be simplified?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to listen for a response then you can remove the dataFormat, the listener and its handler function.  You can also leave out the `request.method` because GET is the default.

```
import flash.net.*;
var url:String = "http://192.168.1.1:1234/";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.name = "Anton Ashardi";
request.data = variables;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
```

If you don't want to send any data along with your request you can also omit the central code block.

Comment: I'm creating an API wrapper class. Anything wrong with keeping the URLLoader as a member variable and reusing it?

Comment: Not that I know of, especially if you are never going to register listeners to it. You can just call `loader.load` with a new request object, or keep the request object as a class member as well and just modify the URLVariables object before sending.