# What is the fastest way to check if a user is connected to the internet in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, connection

I need to check if a user is connected to the internet. What's the fastest way to do that in Flash AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an HTTP GET of a very reliable and fast website, like google.com.

See [AS3 HTTP Get Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746670/how-to-send-a-get-request-in-as3)

Comment: Wouldn't a ping suffice?

Comment: It would, but not as easy to do in AS3 as a simple Get.

Answer (score 1):

Make a request. If it fails - there is no internet :)

Comment: Or the server to which you are making the request is down.

Comment: Assaf answered that 17 seconds before me :) What is more reliable than that? I don't understand what a ping means talking about Flash, but either ways, it may fail because of the same reason.. I agree this is not perfect, but it's good enough in my opinion.

Comment: There's something about having to reach out to someone else's server that doesn't feel right, but I suppose it would suffice.

Comment: Yeah I know it's pretty bad, but unfortunately Adobe are happy with the half-baked cake they've done :) In AIR, there is a way to check network connection status, but pure Flash is like a blind ninja.. edit: By the way, great user profile you've got! :) I'm happy people like you continue to contribute to sites like that and even keep aware of such topics!